# opencv use cuda memory anyway

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

I want to know how much my code is faster with `CUDA`, so I compile `OpenCV` with below switches (including cuda)

```
cmake CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE   \
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local  \
WITH_CUDA=ON    \
ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1   \
CUDA_FAST_MATH=1   \
WITH_CUBLAS=1   \    
INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF  \
OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/saeed/opencv_contrib/modules  \
BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF   ..
```

and I'm working on Linux based machine and with dedicated GPU on my system so how I can measure gpu usage for opencv code? I did that with using

```
$  nvidia-smi
```

command,which give me general information about gpu usage and etc (in `bash`) .

for trace this output I use

```
$ watch -n 0.1 nvidia-smi
```

command,which updates informations every 0.1 second(0.1 second is minimum)

So I have a code like below in opencv(You can see I don't use any cuda function in it)

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
     cv::Mat src(1500,1500,CV_8UC3),res;
     for (int var = 0; var < 70; ++var)
     {
         Canny(src,res,50,150,5);
     }

}
```

So when i run above code I take a screen shot in my `nvidia-smi` page(to know how much gpu ram is in use)

[image]

As you can see there is 23 MiB is in use !!! so why this happen !!if it is normal how we could stop that !? **How to stop GPU for this problem**

Comment: Are you seeing a change in memory usage before and during your code running? It might be normal memory usage.

Comment: No, I force my operating system to not using GPU resources, I add it to my blacklist
If I don't use cuda code it must be zero in all time

Comment: But are you seeing a change in memory usage?

Comment: yeah in moment i run my code I see that memory change form zero to 23 Mib,... but when I use my OS, see video, and another stuff it is zero anyway

Comment: How are  you forcing your OS to not use any GPU?

Comment: `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="" ./my_opencv_code_that_wont_use_gpu`

Comment: The reason this is happening is that your openCV code is linked against some openCV libraries that were built with CUDA capability, and linked against CUDA libraries.  If you want to eliminate this effect, you may want to consider building your OpenCV without GPU support.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks for your answer, `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="" ./my_opencv_code_that_wont_use_gpu` works for me and code don't reserve any memory in GPU, do you know how to do this procedure inside of c++ code? however already I get my answer if you want to post this answer I accept it ... Thank You a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the CUDA runtime indicate that there are no available GPUs with the following [environment variable](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#env-vars):

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="" ./my_opencv_code_that_wont_use_gpu
```

If you want OpenCV to actually not do anything with the GPU, my best guess would be to compile it without CUDA support:

```
cmake CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE   \
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local  \
WITH_CUDA=ON    \    ********MODIFY
ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1   \
CUDA_FAST_MATH=1   \ ********MODIFY
WITH_CUBLAS=1   \    ********MODIFY
INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF  \
OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/saeed/opencv_contrib/modules  \
BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF   ..
```

Comment: It is probably worth noting that just because something linked into OpenCV is establishing a context on the GPU and consuming some memory, it does not mean that OpenCV is actually using the GPU for anything